# O que é ViewHolder Pattern?

Tags: android, design-pattern, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Estou implementando um `RecyclerView` no Android e notei que é necessário criar uma classe chamada `ViewHolder`. Esta [classe parece ser um padrão de projeto](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#compared-to-listview) chamado ViewHolder Pattern, e minhas dúvidas surgem exatamente neste ponto.

---

## Dúvidas

1. O que é ViewHolder Pattern?
2. Qual é a finalidade do ViewHolder Pattern?
3. Quais são seus benefícios?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> O que é ViewHolder Pattern?

Abordagem utilizada para guardar um conjunto de views para que possam ser eficientemente acedidas e reutilizadas, quando necessário.
A finalidade da classe [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) é guardar as views.

> Qual é a finalidade do ViewHolder Pattern?

Evitar o uso repetido de `findViewById()` para obter as referências às views.
Ao serem guardadas num objecto ViewHolder as referencias estão disponíveis de imediato.

> Quais são seus benefícios?

Evitar a perda de performance devido ao uso repetido `findViewById()`.

Comment: Uma dúvida @ramaral, ButterKnife tem uma função semelhante que evita a repetição de chamar o findViewById()... Então podemos dizer que ele está dentro deste padrão ?

Comment: @Matheus Não. O que o ButterKnife faz é gerar, para sim, as chamadas ao método `findViewById()`. Veja a [página principal do ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). Lá, ao ser referido o padrão ViewHolder, é dito que "simplifica", o que é diferente de substituir.

Comment: @ramaral, falando em *Butterknife*, usar o padrão ViewHolder numa activity, e passar ela como parâmetro pra uma classe auxiliar, é uma má prática em relação a eficiência? ou seria melhor passar os objetos em si? ou seria ainda melhor fazer tudo que tem que fazer nas views dentro da própria activity (independente de usar ou não viewholder)?

Comment: @GR_ Lamento mas não consigo perceber o que está perguntando, talvez por falta de contexto. O que quer dizer com "usar o padrão ViewHolder numa activity"?

Comment: @ramaral eu vou criar uma pergunta e deixo o link aqui pra você compreender. Acho mais fácil que explicar tudo em um comentário haha

Comment: @ramaral https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270541/4306