# ViewHolder Pattern em uma Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, view

Vamos supor que eu tenha uma Activity com seu layout e, usando o ButterKnife e o ViewHolder Pattern, eu crio uma classe aninhada em que eu passo a View raíz e injeto o ButterKnife na mesma.
O objetivo seria por exemplo, ao invés de passar View por View para uma classe auxiliar, eu passasse a classe utilizadora do ViewHolder Pattern. Segue um exemplo:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(findViewById(R.id.layout_raiz));

        // faz algumas tarefas que poderiam deixar o código
        // da Activity sujo
        new VerificarLogin(viewHolder);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.et1)
        EditText email;
        @BindView(R.id.et2)
        EditText senha;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

A questão é:

1) Criar um padrão desse tipo, para a Activity, seria uma má prática? Deveria ser usado esse padrão apenas quando fosse necessário a "reciclagem" de Views?

2) Passar uma ViewHolder como parâmetro é uma má prática? (supondo que na classe auxiliar eu use todas as views dentro do ViewHolder)

3) Usando esse tipo de prática na Activity, e passando como parâmetro (como no exemplo acima), eu deveria configurar o objeto **viewHolder = null** quando a Activity fosse destruída?

Comment: Em VerificarLogin você usa as views ou o seu conteúdo?

Comment: eu uso ambos @ramaral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Criar um padrão desse tipo, para a Activity, seria uma má prática? Deveria ser usado esse padrão apenas quando fosse necessário a "reciclagem" de Views?

A finalidade do Padrão ViewHolder é evitar o uso repetido de `findViewById()` para obter as referências às views.
Ele é normalmente referido na utilização da ListView/RecyclerView mas pode e é, nesse sentido/finalidade, utilizado em outras situações.

Quando você declara atributos da Activity para guardar as views e os usa para as aceder em locais diferentes dela, apesar de não ter uma classe para o efeito(ViewHolder), está efectivamente a evitar o uso repetido de `findViewById()`.

> 2) Passar uma ViewHolder como parâmetro é uma má prática? (supondo que na classe auxiliar eu use todas as views dentro do ViewHolder)

Não me parece que seja. É comum usar uma classe para agrupar informações que se relacionam para evitar ter de passar, individualmente, muitos parâmetros a um método.

> 3) Usando esse tipo de prática na Activity, e passando como parâmetro (como no exemplo acima), eu deveria configurar o objeto viewHolder = null quando a Activity fosse destruída?

Quanto muito seria anular o objecto VerificarLogin. O que importa é que o objecto, neste caso VerificarLogin, tenha um "tempo de vida" inferior ao da Activity.